# Join 2 inner join result into one result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, mysqli

Everyone I have a problem. I have two query which is running fine separate. But I want to make into one query I have tried, but those are not work. I need to join two output.

**First Query:**

```
SELECT q_internal_table.q_part_id, 
   q_external_table.q_external_id, 
   q_external_table.q_external_approve, 
   q_external_table.q_order_id, 
   q_internal_table.q_internal_id, 
   q_internal_table.q_internal_approve 
   FROM   (SELECT parts.id                  AS q_part_id, 
           parts.order_id            AS q_order_id, 
           external_reports.id       AS q_external_id, 
           external_reports.approved AS q_external_approve 
    FROM   parts 
           INNER JOIN external_reports 
                   ON( parts.id = external_reports.part_id )) 
   q_external_table 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT parts.id                  AS q_part_id, 
                      internal_reports.id       AS q_internal_id, 
                      internal_reports.approved AS q_internal_approve 
               FROM   parts 
                      INNER JOIN internal_reports 
                              ON( parts.id = internal_reports.part_id )) 
          q_internal_table 
           ON( q_external_table.q_part_id = q_internal_table.q_part_id ) 
   WHERE  ( q_external_table.q_external_approve = 'Y' 
      OR q_internal_table.q_internal_approve = 'Y' )
```

**Second Query:**

```
SELECT q_five_internal_table.q_five_part_id,
   q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_id, 
   q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_approve,
   q_five_external_table.q_five_external_id, 
   q_five_external_table.q_five_external_approve, 
   q_five_external_table.q_five_order_id
   FROM   (SELECT parts.id                  AS q_five_part_id, 
           parts.order_id            AS q_five_order_id, 
           five_way_external_reports.id       AS q_five_external_id, 
           five_way_external_reports.approved AS q_five_external_approve 
    FROM   parts 
           INNER JOIN five_way_external_reports 
                   ON( parts.id = five_way_external_reports.part_id )) 
   q_five_external_table 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT parts.id                  AS q_five_part_id, 
                      five_way_internal_reports.id       AS q_five_internal_id, 
                      five_way_internal_reports.approved AS q_five_internal_approve 
               FROM   parts 
                      INNER JOIN five_way_internal_reports 
                              ON( parts.id = five_way_internal_reports.part_id )) 
          q_five_internal_table 
           ON( q_five_external_table.q_five_part_id = q_five_internal_table.q_five_part_id ) 
  WHERE  ( q_five_external_table.q_five_external_approve = 'Y' 
      OR q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_approve = 'Y' )
```

**First Query Result:**
[image]

**Second Query Result:**
[image]

**I have tried this query:-**

```
SELECT q_internal_external_table.*, 
   q_five_internal_external_table.* 
FROM   (SELECT q_internal_table.q_part_id, 
           q_external_table.q_external_id, 
           q_external_table.q_external_approve, 
           q_external_table.q_order_id, 
           q_internal_table.q_internal_id, 
           q_internal_table.q_internal_approve 
    FROM  (SELECT parts.id                  AS q_part_id, 
                  parts.order_id            AS q_order_id, 
                  external_reports.id       AS q_external_id, 
                  external_reports.approved AS q_external_approve 
           FROM   parts 
                  INNER JOIN external_reports 
                          ON( parts.id = external_reports.part_id )) 
          q_external_table 
          INNER JOIN (SELECT parts.id                  AS q_part_id, 
                             internal_reports.id       AS q_internal_id, 
                             internal_reports.approved AS q_internal_approve 
                      FROM   parts 
                             INNER JOIN internal_reports 
        ON( parts.id = internal_reports.part_id )) 
        q_internal_table 
       ON( q_external_table.q_part_id = q_internal_table.q_part_id ) 
       WHERE  ( q_external_table.q_external_approve = 'Y' 
       OR q_internal_table.q_internal_approve = 'Y' )) 
       q_internal_external_table 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT q_five_internal_table.q_five_part_id, 
       q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_id, 
       q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_approve, 
       q_five_external_table.q_five_order_id, 
       q_five_external_table.q_five_external_id, 
       q_five_external_table.q_five_external_approve 
       FROM   (SELECT parts.id                           AS q_five_part_id, 
       parts.order_id                     AS 
       q_five_order_id 
       , 
      five_way_external_reports.id       AS 
       q_five_external_id, 
       five_way_external_reports.approved AS 
       q_five_external_approve 
       FROM   parts 
       INNER JOIN five_way_external_reports 
       ON( parts.id = five_way_external_reports.part_id )) 
       q_five_external_table 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT parts.id  AS     q_five_part_id, 
       five_way_internal_reports.id       AS 
       q_five_internal_id, 
       five_way_internal_reports.approved AS 
       q_five_internal_approve 
       FROM   parts 
       INNER JOIN five_way_internal_reports 
       ON( parts.id = five_way_internal_reports.part_id )) 
       q_five_internal_table 
       ON ( q_five_external_table.q_five_part_id = 
       q_five_internal_table.q_five_part_id ) 
       WHERE  ( q_five_external_table.q_five_external_approve = 'Y' 
       OR q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_approve = 'Y' )) 
       q_five_internal_external_table 
       ON ( q_internal_external_table.q_part_id = 
       q_five_internal_external_table.q_five_part_id )
```

**QUERY Result:-**
[image]
In this query there are three result. But I want the 7 result in as in the first query result. The three answer is already in the first query result. I need rest 4 too. I think the problem is in `ON q_internal_external_table.q_part_id = q_five_internal_external_table.q_five_part_id`. But don't know how to solve it.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) What's the expected outcome? 2) What have you tried and what went wrong with those tries?

Comment: You mean a UNION - google that

Comment: @Shadow: I updated the question. I want to join the two answer. And I also add the SQL which I have tried.

Comment: Something like `select * from (1st select) as t1 join (2nd select) as t2 on t1.q_part_id = t2.q_five_part_id`.

Comment: Join means what? Pls demonstrate using the 7 + 3 records already in the question.

Comment: @Shadow I modify the question. I think now you have an idea what I am want to do.

Comment: @Avishake: Switch to an outer join, `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` between the two Selects, this will return the non-matching rows with NULLs.

Comment: @dnoeth yes. Great its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special Thanks to @ dnoeth. Great man.

The modified SQL is,

```
select q_internal_external_table.*,q_five_internal_external_table.* from         
(select q_internal_table.q_part_id, 
q_external_table.q_external_id,q_external_table.q_external_approve, 
q_external_table.q_order_id,q_internal_table.q_internal_id, 
q_internal_table.q_internal_approve from(SELECT parts.id as 
q_part_id,parts.order_id as q_order_id,external_reports.id as 
q_external_id,external_reports.approved as q_external_approve from parts 
LEFT join external_reports on(parts.id=external_reports.part_id)) 
q_external_table LEFT join (SELECT parts.id as q_part_id,internal_reports.id 
as q_internal_id,internal_reports.approved as q_internal_approve from parts 
LEFT join internal_reports on(parts.id=internal_reports.part_id)) 
q_internal_table on(q_external_table.q_part_id=q_internal_table.q_part_id) 
where (q_external_table.q_external_approve='Y' or 
q_internal_table.q_internal_approve='Y')) q_internal_external_table LEFT 
join (select q_five_internal_table.q_five_part_id, 
q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_id, 
q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_approve, 
q_five_external_table.q_five_order_id, 
q_five_external_table.q_five_external_id, 
q_five_external_table.q_five_external_approve from (SELECT parts.id as 
q_five_part_id,parts.order_id as q_five_order_id, 
five_way_external_reports.id as q_five_external_id, 
five_way_external_reports.approved as q_five_external_approve from parts 
LEFT join five_way_external_reports on(parts.id= 
five_way_external_reports.part_id)) q_five_external_table LEFT join (SELECT 
parts.id as q_five_part_id,five_way_internal_reports.id as 
q_five_internal_id,five_way_internal_reports.approved as 
q_five_internal_approve from parts LEFT join five_way_internal_reports 
on(parts.id=five_way_internal_reports.part_id)) q_five_internal_table on 
(q_five_external_table.q_five_part_id=q_five_internal_table.q_five_part_id) 
where (q_five_external_table.q_five_external_approve='Y' or 
q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_approve='Y')) 
q_five_internal_external_table on (q_internal_external_table.q_part_id 
=q_five_internal_external_table.q_five_part_id)
```

**The answer: (which I want)** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `UNION`.

Both queries need to have the same amount columns and types. In your case, you need to change the order of the columns selected in order to make the `UNION`.

Should be something like this:

```
SELECT q_internal_table.q_part_id, 
   q_external_table.q_external_id, 
   q_external_table.q_external_approve, 
   q_external_table.q_order_id, 
   q_internal_table.q_internal_id, 
   q_internal_table.q_internal_approve 
   FROM   (SELECT parts.id AS q_part_id, 
           parts.order_id AS q_order_id, 
           external_reports.id AS q_external_id, 
           external_reports.approved AS q_external_approve 
    FROM parts 
           INNER JOIN external_reports 
                   ON( parts.id = external_reports.part_id )) 
   q_external_table 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT parts.id AS q_part_id, 
                      internal_reports.id AS q_internal_id, 
                      internal_reports.approved AS q_internal_approve 
               FROM   parts 
                      INNER JOIN internal_reports 
                              ON( parts.id = internal_reports.part_id )) 
          q_internal_table 
           ON( q_external_table.q_part_id = q_internal_table.q_part_id ) 
   WHERE  ( q_external_table.q_external_approve = 'Y' 
      OR q_internal_table.q_internal_approve = 'Y' )

UNION ALL 

SELECT q_five_internal_table.q_five_part_id,
      q_five_external_table.q_five_external_id,
      q_five_external_table.q_five_external_approve, 
      q_five_external_table.q_five_order_id,
   q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_id, 
   q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_approve   
   FROM   (SELECT parts.id AS q_five_part_id, 
           parts.order_id AS q_five_order_id, 
           five_way_external_reports.id AS q_five_external_id, 
           five_way_external_reports.approved AS q_five_external_approve 
    FROM   parts 
           INNER JOIN five_way_external_reports 
                   ON( parts.id = five_way_external_reports.part_id )) 
   q_five_external_table 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT parts.id AS q_five_part_id, 
                      five_way_internal_reports.id AS q_five_internal_id, 
                      five_way_internal_reports.approved AS q_five_internal_approve 
               FROM parts 
                      INNER JOIN five_way_internal_reports 
                              ON( parts.id = five_way_internal_reports.part_id )) 
          q_five_internal_table 
           ON( q_five_external_table.q_five_part_id = q_five_internal_table.q_five_part_id ) 
  WHERE  ( q_five_external_table.q_five_external_approve = 'Y' 
      OR q_five_internal_table.q_five_internal_approve = 'Y' )
```

Notice I've changed the order of the columns in the second query to match the type of the first.

Comment: Whitout knowing the expected output it might be a `UNION` or `EXCEPT` or `INTERSECT`, too :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But in the answer second query result is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated query seems to be correct (semantically), if we assume that the end objective of your query is to find a parts.id in the following tables:
external_reports, internal_reports, five_way_external_reports,  five_way_internal_reports

Union is to be used when combining the rows of query 1 and query 2.

However, if you are trying to find matching columns (join clause), then the JOIN and not UNION is to be used.

Also, please try EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN EXTENDED prefix to your queries to understand the query plan.